# Bean Validation constraints in a shared library

Tags: bean-validation

I have many jsf2 web projects that use the same validation constraints.

1. Can I put all these constraints in a shared library?
2. If yes, can I supply traslations for the validation messages?
3. If yes, how can I achieve it in a standard way?
4. Is the following package structure correct?

commons.jar library:

```
commons.jar
    |
    + library
    |   |
    |   + CustomConstraint1.class
    |   + CustomConstraint2.class
    |
    + ValidationMessages_it.properties
    + ValidationMessages_en.properties
    + ValidationMessages_de.properties
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bundling is right for a standalone jar. It won't work if you drop this jar into a ear/war with it's own constraints and a ValidationMessages.properties in the root of the classpath.

Comment: If you are using Hibernate 5.2 or greater, you can solve the duplicate resource problem by configuring a PlatformResourceBundleLocator per my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/33442715/1108305

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Can I put all these constraints in a shared library?

Yes, you can.

> 1. If yes, can I supply traslations for the validation messages?

Yes, this is also possible.

> 1. If yes, how can I achieve it in a standard way?

For example, you have a constraint like this:

```
package com.example.constraints;

@Target({
        ElementType.FIELD,
        ElementType.PARAMETER,
        ElementType.METHOD
})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {
    FooValidator.class
})
public @interface Foo
{
    String message() default "{com.example.constraints.Foo.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Specify a `ValidationMessages.properties` in the root of your class path (For the application's default language). For extra locales you should specify a `ValidationMessages_[locale].properties` file. For a Dutch locale it should be `ValidationMessages_nl.properties`.

Then in those files you define your message variable as a key and the message as a value like this:

```
com.example.constraints.Foo.message=Foo is not valid
```

Comment: Hi siebz0r, thank you for the response. May you have a look at the new point in my question and update your answer? Thank you again

Comment: It's a good news but unfortunately it does not work for me. If I put this library in a web app _{com.example.constraints.Foo.message}_ is shown as message. It works a bit if I have a composite constraint with message key in another position but it stops working if I add a ValidationMessages_it.properties, for exemple, in the WEB-INF/classes folder. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599208/multiple-validationmessages-properties

Comment: @Alf Per my comment on your accepted answer above, if you are using Hibernate 5.2 or greater, you can solve the duplicate resource problem by configuring a PlatformResourceBundleLocator per my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/33442715/1108305